# Diagonal background mask with CSS3?

Tags: css, background, mask

I'm wondering how to achieve a diagonal overlay/mask such as the image below:

[image: this image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since learned that there are multiple ways to achieve this effect both using SVG, CSS and image background overlays. I decided to go with a pseudo element and using the `transform` property.

https://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/VExQGm

```
.box:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 150px;
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   background: #fff;
   transform: rotate(-15deg);
   transform-origin: center center;
   left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using a regular image that contains the mask, giving it a high z-index, and absolutely positioning it on top of the other image:

```
.bottom-mask {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:400;
    background:url(../images/bottom-mask.png) no-repeat 50% 0
}
```

Comment: I've marked this answer as correct as historically this is true and is still a viable answer to anyone still searching for a solution to this question.